# How to insert list items (li) between existing items in a list (ul) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, transformation

some time ago I've written a transformation to output data from an xml file to html. It works, BUT it's an awful messy code and since I don't write Javascript often I can't figure out how I ever got this code running.

As of now this code inserts li-items (each containing a link) into an empty ul-container with the id="xmlMenuRight".

The new situation is that this container is no longer empty. 
There is going to be 2 hard coded items. One at first position and the other at last position.

All li-items from this transformation shall be inserted between the existing first and last li-item.

I assume it going to be a mix of insertBefore and appendChild. But I am lost here, nearly as much as comprehending my own mess of code.
Some help and advice on how to do this the best way is highly appreciated.

input from file:

```
<item>
    <origin>name of a country or region</origin>
    <sitemap>no</sitemap>
    <link>/folder/2015-subFolder/filename.html</link>
    <title>Dining Room</title>
</item>
```

(the 2 fields named origin and sitemap are irrelevant).

transformation during a xmlhttprequest

```
var xmlhttp = "";
var xmlDoc = "";
function loadXMLDoc(dname)  {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   }   // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    else
        {   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }       // for IE6

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    var inputList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item');
    for (var i=0;i<inputList.length;i++) {
        var x = document.createElement('li');

        x.setAttribute('typeof',"ListItem");
        x.setAttribute('property',"itemListElement");
        x.className = 'side';

        var y = document.createElement('meta');
        y.setAttribute ('content',[i+1]);
        y.setAttribute ('property',"position");

        var lnk1 = document.createElement('a');
        var lnk2 = getNodeValue(inputList[i],'link');
        var lnk3 = getNodeValue(inputList[i],'title');

        lnk1.setAttribute('href',lnk2);
        lnk1.setAttribute('typeof',"WebPage");
        lnk1.setAttribute('property',"item");

        var ele3 = document.createElement('span');
        ele3.setAttribute('property',"name");
        ele3.innerHTML = lnk3;

        var ele4 = lnk1.appendChild(ele3);

        x.appendChild(lnk1);
        x.appendChild(y);

        document.getElementById('navigation2').appendChild(x);
                }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET',dname,true); //asynchronous method
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

function getNodeValue(obj,tag)

```
{   return obj.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;   }
```

current output per li-item:

```
<li class="side" property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="/folder/2015-subFolder/filename.html"><span property="name">Dining Room</span></a><meta property="position" content="1"></li>
```

anticipated new list:

```
<ul id="xmlMenuRight">
    <li>first item is hard coded</li>
    ...
    inserts from transformation above go here (the amount of li-items varies)
    ...
    <li>last item is also hard coded</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it is to just give the last hard coded item an id and use `insertBefore` on it.

Comment: @DonovanM :Your feedback helped me in finding the easiest solution (after making  `insertBefore` do what I want. The solution was to simply move the ID in the ul-tag one line down to the first li-tag and do `appendChild` from there. Like so:`<ul><li id="xmlMenuRight">first item is hard coded</li>`

Comment: Why a down-vote? The least the down-voter should do is to please give a reason. The question was properly posted according to the rules in stackoverflow. ...and remember: not everybody is equally smart.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Not sure why you got downvoted.

Comment: @DonovanM :I know it was not you nor PetrHejda. Most likelyit was the person who deleted the answer after me commenting it. No big deal. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **take away the last item and re-append it** after you've appended the dynamic content.

This is hard coded:

```
<ul id="xmlMenuRight">
    <li>first item is hard coded</li>
    <li>last item is also hard coded</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JS:

```
var liElems = document.getElementById('xmlMenuRight').getElementsByTagName('li');
var lastChild = liElems[liElems.length-1];
document.getElementById('xmlMenuRight').removeChild(lastChild);

for (var i=0;i<inputList.length;i++) {
    // your code
    document.getElementById('xmlMenuRight').appendChild(x);
}

document.getElementById('xmlMenuRight').appendChild(lastChild);
```

Note: Using [lastChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp) property can be tricky because it may consider whitespace as the last child of the <ul>. That's why i didn't use it in my example.

Comment: Your answer is correct. this works fine based on the way I phrased the question. What I neglected it the fact that all this happens during a XMLHttpRequest. So the trouble I am facing now is how to implement your solution into the existing code. Therefore I am going to adapt the question.